# Replacing certain letters with symbol

Tags: c#

I'm doing an assignment for school which includes replacing every letter except A,a,S,s,N,n in a string.

So far I figured out how to replace these letters, which is the opposite of the assignment.

Can someone help?

This is what I have rn.

```
string texti = null;
Console.WriteLine ("");
Console.WriteLine ("Put in your sentence ..");
texti = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine ("You entered the following ..");
Console.WriteLine (texti);

texti = texti.Replace ("a", "*").Replace ("A", "*").Replace ("s", "*").Replace ("S", "*").Replace ("N", "*").Replace ("n", "*");

Console.WriteLine ("Your new text");
Console.WriteLine (texti);
```

but again .. this above is the opposite of my assignment

Here I have a similar project, but this replaces everything with @

```
Console.WriteLine();

for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{

    newtext = newtext + "@";
}

Console.WriteLine(newtext);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Add the code you have done so far so that we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: You want to replace those letters with what?

Comment: @beggi go to your Instructor and ask them what Symbols they want you to replace since we don't know.. this is a very poor question at best.. read the following [How To Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @beeggi do not post code in your comments update the question / edit it and post your code there ..

Comment: @MethodMan noted - thanks :)  I want to replace every letter in the sentence with "*", except the following: A,a,S,s,N,n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string texti = string.Empty;
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("Put in your sentence ..");
texti = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("You entered the following ..");
Console.WriteLine(texti);
foreach (char str in texti)
{
    switch (str)
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
        case 'S':
        case 's':
        case 'N':
        case 'n':
            {
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                texti = texti.Replace(str, '*');
                break;
            }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Your new text");
Console.WriteLine(texti);
```

Comment: okay this works brilliantly, I also added " " for the blank spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ:

```
var letters = "AaSsNn";
var result = String.Join("", input.Select(c => letters.Any(x => x == c) ? c : '*'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple loop to build a new string. but with some checks and modifications.

```
string text = Console.ReadLine();
string newText = "";
string ommit = "AaSsNn"; // should not remove these.


for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    if (ommit.Contains(text[i])) // if character exist in ommit.
    {
        newText += text[i]; // put the original
    }
    else
    {
        newText += "*"; // replace
    }
}
```

You can use a bit longer condition instead of using string like `ommit`.

```
if(text[i].ToString().ToUpper() == "A" ||
   text[i].ToString().ToUpper() == "S" ||
   text[i].ToString().ToUpper() == "N")
```